# In React how can I append values to functional state when it is a dependency of useEffect without triggering another API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a todo list app which users can read and save items to.  Here, `Todo` is a functional component that queries an API for the users current items on their list using the `useEffect()` hook.  When a successful response is received the data is added to the component's state using `useState()` and rendered as part of the `ItemList` component.

When a user submits the form within the `AddItemForm` component a call back is fired that updates the state of `newItem`, a dependency of `useEffect`, which triggers another call to the API and a re-render of the component.

Logically, everything above works.  However, it seems wrong to make an extra request to the API simply to receive the data that is already available but I can't find the correct pattern that would allow me to push the `item` available in `useCallback` to the `items` array without causing `useEffect` to loop infinitely yet still update the `ItemList` component.

Is there away for my app to push new date from the form submission to `items` array whilst updating the view and only calling the API once when the page loads?

```
function Todo() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://example.com/items').then(
      (response) => {
        setItems(response.data.items);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    );
  }, [newItem]);

  const updateItemList = useCallback((item) => {
    setNewItem(item);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <AddItemForm callback={updateItemList} />
      <ItemList items={items} />
    </>
  );
}


function ItemList(props) {
  const { items } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      { items
        && items.map((item) => <p>{item.description}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call API only on start by removing `newItem` from `useEffect(...,[])`.
Then add item to the items by destructuring in setItems:

```
  const updateItemList = (item) => {
    setItems([...items, item]);
  }
```